# Bash script corrupting my PATH

Tags: bash, terminal

The following script reverses an install script (removes everything the other script installed). The script completes and does it task, but thereafter my terminal fails almost every command complaining that `bash: /usr/bin/sudo: No such file or directory`

I invoke the script as follows: `bash -x remove-all.sh`

Gives me a bugged terminal on both current Ubuntu and Suse
I don't know enough about bash to know what causes this 
Can you help?

Thanks, Yucca

**Code:**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo umount -a -t vboxsf
sudo rm -rf ~/idea-IC-111.167
sudo rm -rf ~/Desktop/netbeans-7.1.desktop
sudo rm -rf ~/.netbeans
sudo rm -rf ~/.m2
sudo rm -rf ~/NetBeansProjects
sudo rm -rf ~/IdeaProjects
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/maven
sudo rm -rf /usr/lib/jvm
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/java
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/mvn
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin/netbeans
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin idea.sh
echo 'done'

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
sudo rm -rf /usr/bin idea.sh
```

Aaaah! You're removing `/usr/bin` recursively! Did you mean:

```
sudo rm -f /usr/bin/idea.sh
```

?

Comment: reminds me of [https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/issues/123](https://github.com/MrMEEE/bumblebee-Old-and-abbandoned/issues/123)

Comment: @James Mclaughlin Thanks, Lucky I test everything in a virtual system used exactly for testing VirtualBox FTW